# Reload HTML table after every AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

My sequential AJAX calls keep appending rows to my HTML table, which I don't want. I want my table to be refreshed/reload on every call with new data, and not appended.

My Code:

```
var data = $('#data_input').val();
var tableRef = document.getElementById('data_table');

$.getJSON("/data/"+data, function(dataState)
{
    // ...
    for(var dataId in dataState)
    {
        var row = document.createElement("tr");
        // creating new cells in a row with the data
        tableRef.appendChild(row);
    }
}
```

So I'm fetching the reference to my HTML table with `var tableRef = document.getElementById('data_table');`, in the `for`-loop, I'm creating rows and appending them to the HTML table with `tableRef.appendChild(row);`. The problem is that on any sequent `$.getJSON` call, the table gets further appended. How do I refresh my table on every call, ie. delete data from the previous call, and fill data from a new call?

Comment: `$('#data_table tr').remove()` ?

Comment: empty the table content before appending new data `$('#data_table').empty()`

Comment: thanks guys, this worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the rows after getting the data from the server

```
$.getJSON("/data/"+data, function(dataState) {

   $("#data_table tr").remove();
       //...

        for(var dataId in dataState) {


                var row = document.createElement("tr");

               // creating new cells in a row with the data

                tableRef.appendChild(row);
            }

        }

    });
```

Note that it will also remove the headers of the table, if you want to remove the data only and keep the headers, you only remove the rows inside `tbody` tag i.e `$("#data_table tbody tr").remove();`

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to delete every children of type `tr` with `$("#data_table tr").remove();`.

So you'll have something like this:

```
var data = $('#data_input').val();
var tableRef = document.getElementById('data_table');

$.getJSON("/data/"+data, function(dataState)
{
    // ...
    $("#data_table tr").remove();
    for(var dataId in dataState)
    {
        var row = document.createElement("tr");
        // creating new cells in a row with the data
        tableRef.appendChild(row);
    }
}
```